# Where is the Touch ID data stored?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, security, touch-id

I would like to 'backup' my Touch ID data or configuration.  What file(s) would I need to backup in order to preserve that data and can I simply restore those files to set it up again on the same or another machine.

Comment: I’m going to tag this assuming you have a portable Mac and not a Bluetooth keyboard that uses Touch ID.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is impossible by design. The biometric data is computed into a numeric representation that is then stored in an encrypted file. No fingerprint is stored in the clear, made accessible to you or to Apple or transmitted off-device. The only cryptographic keys able to decrypt the saved biometric information rests in the Secure Enclave and that is designed to be tamper resistant and no backup intended. The data remains on the hardware and can be erased when requested.

From [documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204587):

> Your fingerprint data is encrypted, stored on disk, and protected with a key available only to the Secure Enclave. Your fingerprint data is used only by the Secure Enclave to verify that your fingerprint matches the enrolled fingerprint data. It can’t be accessed by the OS on your device or by any applications running on it. It's never stored on Apple servers, it's never backed up to iCloud or anywhere else, and it can't be used to match against other fingerprint databases.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149683/discussion-on-answer-by-aivar-paalberg-where-is-the-touch-id-data-stored); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.